# Rgdal readOGR error all Features NULL MacOS

Tags: r, macos, shapefile, r-sf, rgdal

I am attempting to guide a colleague through working with Shapefiles in R using sf and rgdal packages. The example code I supplied:

```
dz_boundaries <- readOGR(dsn="~/Downloads/SG_DataZoneBdry_2011", layer="SG_DataZone_Bdry_2011")
```

The example ESRI Shapefile was downloaded from: https://data.gov.uk/dataset/ab9f1f20-3b7f-4efa-9bd2-239acf63b540/data-zone-boundaries-2011

I am able to read this Shapefile in and manipulate it on both a home Mac and Windows machine without issue. However, my colleague is met with the error when attempting to follow the code with their Mac:

```
Error in readOGR: no features found
ogrInfo:all features NULL
```

I have attempted to solve this by:

- Ensuring path is correct using auto tab
- Ensuring RStudio has permission to access files and folders
- Using st_read() from sf package instead - error message says file does not exist
- Confirmed ESRI Shapefile gdb folder exists and all component elements exist and are correct size
- Using dsn=path.expand('path') moderation as suggested in a similar question
- Downgrading to a previous stable version of R (3.6.1)
- Updating packages and aligning versions
- Restarting and re-downloading ESRI Shapefile
- Checking if their version of MacOS is the same as mine

But their machine seems to be unable to acknowledge the files existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use the URL in the link "ESRI Shapefile Download" in your provided link, `sf::read_sf` and `rgdal::readOGR` work for me.

```
# Download shapefile
path <- "http://sedsh127.sedsh.gov.uk/Atom_data/ScotGov/ZippedShapefiles/SG_DataZoneBdry_2011.zip"

temp_shapefile <- tempfile()
download.file(path, temp_shapefile)
temp_dir <- tempdir()
unzip(temp_shapefile, exdir = temp_dir)
```

```
# sf
DataZone_sf <- sf::read_sf(file.path(temp_dir,'SG_DataZone_Bdry_2011.shp'))
plot(head(DataZone_sf['ResPop2011']))
```

```
# rgdal
DataZone_rgdal <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn=temp_dir, layer="SG_DataZone_Bdry_2011")
plot(head(DataZone_rgdal))
```

My session info. On a PC, but hopefully the above code provides a more easily reproducible example on the Mac.

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

rgdal_1.5-10
sf_0.9-4
```